# Expression with Boole

Tags: simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics, syntax, expression-manipulation, markov-chains

Let us have an expression for example, this:

```
2 (-1 + p) (3 - 4 p + 2 p^2) Boole[\[FormalX] == 1] - 9 (1 - 2 p + p^2) Boole[\[FormalX] == 2] ...
```

For the whole context, it is a product of function `dist = StationaryDistribution[DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P]] // First`

Now I would like to manipulate with the expression when `X == 1`, `X == 2`, etc.

Maybe it is not Mathematica idiomatical way. The result I would like to achieve in my case is a standard stationary matrix for the Markov process, so something like this.

```
{{dist_when_X==1, dist_when_X==2, ...}}
```

The solution with `Simplify[dist, x==1]` does not work (but not sure if it should work anyway).

Comment: this?`P = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 
    0}, {{0, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}}];
PDF[P[t], x] // First`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Xminer for a hint. The solution is this:

```
{{PDF[ DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P][Infinity], 1],PDF[ DiscreteMarkovProcess[1,P][Infinity], 2], ...}} // MatrixForm
```

where `P` is Markov transition matrix and the second PDF argument is the value of Boole.